# In which comic does Batman travel back in time to the night of his parents’ murder?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics, batman, episode-identification

I'm looking for the comic book/one-shot where Batman is somehow hurled back in time to the night of his parents' murder. It was here that he realized that there IS NO Joe Chill. Facing the hard-learnt truth he sees that he was the one who  murdered the Waynes. If he doesn't, there will be no Batman.

I read a short summary of something like this a long time ago. Is it part of some alternate Earth story line or a one-shot comic book?

Comment: How long ago had you read this? What did the cover look like?

Comment: @Edlothiad About a year ago. Too late to ask the question i guess :P I read it on the internet and just I want to find out its source. Because it did sound interesting

Comment: Reddit Discussion maybe? - https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/38of8i/discussion_what_do_you_think_would_be_the/

Comment: https://www.tickld.com/x/jaw/this-guy-just-changed-the-way-we-see-batman-mind-blown

Comment: @Paulie_D My itch is scratched.. So it was nothing that I imagined to be; just a fan theory. Well, that's a little disappointing :(

Comment: I remember one where he wound up in a universe where the shooting had not yet happened, but which also lacked superheroes, even in mythology, leading to him wondering whether he should let his parents die so that his alternate self would become Batman and the world's only hero.

Comment: [Could it have been this](https://www.reddit.com/r/batman/comments/1y4o26/batman_has_to_kill_his_own_parents/) I didn't read the whole thing but it seemed to be along the same lines. Also a year ago isn't really a long time ;)

Answer (score 12):

The closest match I know of is the "[To Kill a Legend](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_500)" storyline from *Detective Comics Vol 1 500*. In that issue, the Phantom Stranger takes Batman and Robin into a world where time has moved differently, and his parents have not yet been gunned down. Batman faces the decision of whether he should save this alternate set of parents, knowing that that would mean no Batman, someone who has saved thousands of lives over the years. Complicating things, a bit of research shows that this world lacks any heroes, to the point that they don't even have mythological heroes. And, of course, it's barely even a question as to what he decides.

[image: Batman deciding that he must save a life if he can]

> Despite the moral conflicts of the whole ordeal, Batman's intervention causes the event in which the Waynes are killed, although Chill is now not part of the event. Realizing his mistake, Batman saves the Waynes and a young version of himself, who was a spoiled and obnoxious little kid. Having saved the Waynes, the Phantom Stranger returns the heroes to their own world, but the deed has changed the young Bruce Wayne's life, who now changes his demeanor and wants to become the "Bat Creature" who saved them. The Batman will exist, although this time is not because of vengeance, but for a rather inspiring motivation.

[image: Batman saving the Waynes]

[image: Alternate Bruce inspired to become something greater]

There's an interesting analysis of the storyline [here](http://comicsalliance.com/ask-chris-316-to-kill-a-legend/), which harps on the whole "no concept of a hero" thing, and how it beggars belief.

Comment: I'd seen that and contemplated answering with it, but the story is significantly different in my opinion.

Comment: Although finding out that what I wanted was just a fan theory, @FuzzyBoots, you have peaked my interest with your answer. This storyline seems interesting as well. Seeing a Bat with no trauma and someone who now inspires and motivates, something cool.

Comment: @Edlothiad: {nods} I felt it was close enough that it might have been a muddled recollection. Batman having to decide whether his parents live or die because there *must* be a Batman. It's less direct, but still similar in spirit.

Comment: I just assumed they'd read a reddit fan theory.

Comment: @Shreedhar: “you have peaked my interest with your answer” — piqued.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Oy, some of the things I've seen... the number of times newspapers have said "grown weary" when they mean "grown wary", or one recent official email I saw of a resignation where they claimed they were avoiding "burying the lead"...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite my bad man. my bad :p

Comment: I have faith that your badness has peaked, Shreedhar. @FuzzyBoots: tiredness leads to caution. Caution leads to fear. Fear leads to bad grammar. Yoda said that, and if anyone knows about bad grammar, it’s that guy.

Answer (score 3):

It was a fanfic on Reddit 2 years ago.

[What do you think would be the craziest reveal that could occur in comics?](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/38of8i/discussion_what_do_you_think_would_be_the/crws9l3/)